# $rootScope cyrillic encoding on page reload

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

Here is my Authetication service (I'm using PassportJS):

```
 $rootScope.currentUser = $cookieStore.get('user');
```

Now when I'm trying to bind `$rootScope` value:

```
 <p ng-bind="currentUser.username"></p>
```

It encodes correct Cyrillic symbols. But when I'm reloading page I get: `ΜÑÐºÐ¸Ð¼Ð±Ð°ÐΜÐ²`

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @NewDev i think plunker will not show the problem, cause the problem only appear on page reload.

Comment: Plunker supports page reloads. You can open a plunker in a separate window and reload.

Comment: @NewDev http://plnkr.co/edit/xjYfq3Tyl7mISjbqKXq7?p=preview

Comment: Ok, but I can't reproduce the problem. On page reload it works correctly

Comment: @NewDev i think there is a problem in my server - where i use passport for authentication. But when I try latin words, every encoding works correctly. May be something wrong here: `app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user));
    res.send(req.user);
});`
?

Comment: This, by itself, doesn't show the problem to me.